# Get URL Google search same page

Tags: search

I have this code, `Google` search results on the same page

```
   <div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
     <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
       google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
       {
         var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('XXXX:XXXX');
         customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
         customSearchControl.setLinkTarget(google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_BLANK);
         customSearchControl.draw('cse');
       }, true);

     </script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

But I want the search results show on the same page after Click on the link

What is a `URL` to do this?

Example:

```
https://www.mysite.com/search?q=

<a href="https://www.mysite.com/search?q=food">food</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search "moon" within www.bbc.com:

https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=moon+site%3Awww.bbc.com

Try "moon site:www.bbc.com" in Google search box.